# How to change the order of ProjectReference tag in vcproj or vcxproj?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vcxproj, vcproj

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2019 to build a c++ project
I have a solution and three projects in it
one is for the executable and others are for the static libraries

Now I want to change the order of linking the libraries for the executable
And finally found that they are linked in the order of its order in `project.vcxproj`
I changed the order manually with text editor and finally succeeded to get the result

But I don't know how to do it in Visual Studio GUI
If the libraries are described as below in my `project.vcxproj`
Can I change the order of the libraries with Visual Studio GUI?

```sh
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ALibrary\ALibrary.vcxproj">
      <Project>{dbc3f07c-3bf9-4582-99c8-cbd8fe344e5c}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BLibrary\BLibrary.vcxproj">
      <Project>{fbbe1fd4-e968-40d8-aab8-e2a54e9c9268}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the project build order. You need to right click your projects solution-> select "Project build order" from the drop down and the set your order.

For more details reffer to the below link. I think the website explains your question in a good way with screen shots.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/inthetechpit.com/2019/07/09/set-project-build-order-in-visual-studio/amp/

Comment: Thank you Mr.Ranadhir, but sadly the page shows how to set-up build order not linking order for the executable